# how to initialize a variable that reference a property directly and that property change when the variable change

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I have the bool isDamagable in a player health script and I want to change from another script "turn invisible"

but this code `bool isDamagable01 = GetComponent<playerHealth>().isdamagable;` won't work because it is making a copy of isdamagable and not a direct reference. I've tried looking at ref and out but they can only be used inside functions.

excuse me if there are any logic holes

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by that? `bool` as a value type .. it will always be passed on as copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache the component.

```
void Awake()
{
    playerHealth = GetComponent<playerHealth>();
}
```

and in script when isDamagable01 is changed change playerHealth.isdamagable.

```
public class SomeClass{

public bool isDamagable01;

//...some code



public void ChangeIsDamagable01(){

//... change isDamagable01
playerHealth.isdamagable = isDamagable01
}
```

If u need to be called this method automatically when variable changed - use this method to change variable and make isDamagable01 is private :)

```
public void ChangeIsDamagable01(bool changedIsDamagable01){

//... change isDamagable01
isDamagable01 = changedIsDamagable01;

playerHealth.isdamagable = isDamagable01;
}

}
```

Or u can do this

```
public bool isDamagable01
{
    get
    {
        return isDamagable01;
    }
    set
    {
        isDamagable01 = value;
        ChangeIsDamagable01();
    }
}
```

Comment: great but is there a way for the function to be called automatically ?

Comment: @Mohammad_io_ it be called automatically if u change variable isDamagable01 in this method. Or u can put this method to another where variable is changed :)

Answer (score 1):

You could of course convert this into a property and do e.g.

```
bool isDamagable01 => GetComponent<playerHealth>().isdamagable;
```

however, this now does a `GetComponent` call every single time you access the property again.

Instead you should rather simply cache the component reference

```
[SerializeField] private playerHealth _playerHealth;

void Awake()
{
    if(_playerHealth) _playerHealth = GetComponent<playerHealth>();
}
```

and then always access the flag through that

```
if(_playerHealth.isDamageable01)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make isDamage as public object. With this way, you can control that boolean directly from another script. For instance in player health script use isDamagable like this;

```
//Use a public boolean with any value as you wish
public bool isDamagable = true;
```

In the other script, access this boolean and control as you wish in a method;

```
void ChangeIsDamagable() {
     gameObject.GetComponent<playerHealth>().isDamagable = false;
}
```